PowerShell - change DarkRed color
A little colorblindness problem: [ConsoleColor]::DarkRed (and also Red) is like nearly invisible for me. I have to select the text in order to be able to read it.
I've been configuring some stuff in PowerShell to make things more readable:
$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'Yellow'

Very cool, but of course some apps, libs, tools etc do something like this:
Write-Host "Error!" -ForegroundColor DarkRed

So basically I want to overwrite [ConsoleColor]::DarkRed with something else. I've been looking into Reflection but it doesn't seem to be possible.
Any way to achieve this?

If it's an external app and is writing to stdout or stderr you may be able to replace the VT escape sequences with regex and change the color to whatever you like


Preface:

The answer below only solves the problem for Write-Host calls - not also for colored output produced by other commands, notably external programs.

In order to generically re-color output from any executable, you'd have to write a filter that post-processes any command's output and selectively replaces ANSI/VT escape sequences using regular expressions, as Santiago has already noted.

However, even that is not a complete solution on Windows, as there are legacy Win32 console APIs that do not use ANSI/VT escape sequences for coloring; in fact, Write-Host uses them.
Thus both writing a filter (which you could call automatically, from a custom Out-Default implementation) and wrapping Write-Host as is as close to a complete solution as you'll get.




You can take advantage of PowerShell's command precedence and define a custom function named Write-Host that shadows the built-in cmdlet, and calls the latter with modified arguments.
If you place the following in your $PROFILE file, all (non-module-qualified) calls to Write-Host will effectively turn -ForegroundColor Red and -ForegroundColor DarkRed into -ForegroundColor Yellow - adjust as needed.
Note:

The code below is a so-called proxy function, whose skeleton was created using the method described in the bottom section of this answer.

Modifying the original arguments is performed via the automatic $PSBoundParameters variable.


function global:Write-Host {
  <#
  .ForwardHelpTargetName Write-Host
  .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet
  #>
  [CmdletBinding(HelpUri = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2097137', RemotingCapability = 'None')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
    [Alias('Msg', 'Message')]
    [System.Object]
    ${Object},
  
    [switch]
    ${NoNewline},
  
    [System.Object]
    ${Separator},
  
    [System.ConsoleColor]
    ${ForegroundColor},
  
    [System.ConsoleColor]
    ${BackgroundColor})
  
  begin {

    # Translate -ForegroundColor Red / DarkRed to a different color of choice.
    if (($fgColor = $PSBoundParameters.ForegroundColor) -and $fgColor -in 'Red', 'DarkRed') {
      $PSBoundParameters.ForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
    }

    $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
    $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
  
    $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
  }
  
  process {
    try {
      $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    }
    catch {
      $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
  }
  
  end {
    try {
      $steppablePipeline.End()
    }
    catch {
      $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
  }

}


This didn't work with a quick test I performed (an executable) but I assume it works only when executing other PS1 scripts that use Dark(Red) directly...

I'll have to do some research on how to "replace ANSI/VT escape sequences" as I'm not sure how that can be achieved globally on Windows. I also wonder if that is going to do much: for VT sequences to work you need to update the registry key VirtualTerminalLevel. But since color output is already working without changing the registry, I'm guessing that these tools are not using VT sequences?

Yes, that is the implication; as noted in the preface, Write-Host itself does that. While you can override the latter, you're out of luck for external programs that do that (unless you can find a way to hook into the relevant WinAPI function).

As for replacing ANSI/VT sequences, to elaborate slightly on the preface: You'll have to write a regex-based filter command that accepts pipeline input and identifies ANSI/VT escape sequences that constitute color specifications and replace them selectively - a nontrivial effort involving regular expressions; there may be tools / libraries that can help with that, but I don't know; a common task is to remove such escape sequences, but your use case requires selective modification of them. But, as noted: this won't help for commands that don't use such sequences for colored console output
